# Is it possible to let the Router Interface show its IP address in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Is it possible to let the Router Interface show its IP address?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only write text descriptions by yourself.

Comment: this should be a comment.